# give format number on form php

Tags: jquery, formatting, number-formatting

I am trying to formating agent fee received form (using dots. like you can see on the pict below, agent fee received number is come from 5% Price. it automatically calculating using jquery and give the value 5000. the question is how to formating this number and give dots when hit thousand? the form code is bellow

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Agent Fee received (Rp)</label>
  <div class="input-group"> 
      <input readonly type="text"  class="form-control" id="agent_fee_received" name="agent_fee_received" autocomplete="off"  maxlength="20">
      <input type="hidden" name="agent_fees_received" id="agent_fees_received">

  </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){

var Tripagent_feeReceived = 0 ;
var Tripagent_fee = 0 ;

 if (TripRatepercentage!="0")
 {
   Tripagent_fee = Trippublish_price-(Trippublish_price*(
TripRatepercentage/100));
   Tripagent_feeReceived= Trippublish_price*(TripRatepercentage/100);
  }

$("#agent_fee").val(Tripagent_fee);
$("#agent_fee_received").val(Tripagent_feeReceived);
 }
```

[image: form]

Comment: Post your `jquery` code as well since you are not calculating in `php`

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it by your self.

```js
function fmoney(s, n) {
    n = n > 0 && n <= 20 ? n : 2;
    s = parseFloat((s + "").replace(/[^\d\.-]/g, "")).toFixed(n) + "";
    var l = s.split(".")[0].split("").reverse(),
        r = s.split(".")[1];
    t = "";
    for (i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
        t += l[i] + ((i + 1) % 3 == 0 && (i + 1) != l.length ? "," : "");
    }
    return t.split("").reverse().join("") + "." + r;
}

console.log(fmoney(1234.5678, 2));
```